# Exchange 2010 being blacklisted

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, blacklist

Let me start with thanking everyone for trying to help.  First, let me fill everyone to the environment we are running.  We are using Exchange 2010 in virtual Windows 2008 R2 (VMWare 4.5).  We are using Symantec Mail Security for Microsoft Exchange to filter our emails as well as firewall.  Recently, we have been blacklisted.  I have checked the Exchange queue to see if we have been taken over by spammers, but I saw nothing in it to indicate that.  We are running anti-virus on  **every**  PC/laptop and we get reports back if anyone gets infected.  What are we missing?  Anything we need to check/do?  We do a lot of mass mailings, however, we do have permission as well it's in our signature line and people know how to be removed from our list (we do testing, so results are being emailed to clients).  I guess the issue is how do we keep from being blacklisted?  What would be good steps on that?

**Note:**  I understand this might have been asked in the past or that I might have omitted something, so please point me to the right direction and/or ask questions!!!

Thank you!

Comment: There are several operations that manage blacklists, in most cases there's an associated website that explains the reason you got on there and the procedure to get off.  So first question, do you know what blacklist(s) you're on?

Comment: The one we got on was Spamhaus, more specifically Spamhaus XBL.

Comment: Well they have a [nice FAQ](http://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/Spamhaus%20XBL) and the first point explains nicely what the common causes of being listed are.  My initial guess is that you are acting as an [open relay](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=324958) but checking your IP in their [lookup tool](http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/) will probably give your more details.

Comment: @fvu We are no longer listed and I am 100% sure, we are not acting as open relay.